# leaflet map crs is 3857 but coordinates 4326

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, latitude-longitude, epsg

I am developing my first leaflet applications. So [this is my trial application demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x9k0y3v9/).

```
       var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
                maxZoom: 18,

            });

        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 12).addLayer(osm);
```

I am getting the CRS of the map, and CRS is EPSG:3857.

```
 console.log("map crs: " + map.options.crs.code)
```

I can add a point data with EPSG:4326 coordinates.

```
L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
.bindPopup('A popup.')
.openPopup();
```

But I can not add EPSG:3857 coordinates.

```
    L.marker([5732953.77585,-10018.7582914]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A popup.')
    .openPopup();
```

This goes wrong place.

Comment: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-conversion-methods on a appropriate layer or some other projection tool (like proj4js or similar).

Comment: No, those won't help, as they are not CRS-aware, they are screen-coordinates-aware.

Answer (score 10):

This is a feature, not a bug. Most Leaflet users are not aware that the map's *display* CRS is different from the map's *data* CRS, and that's fine; it makes life simpler for most people.

If your question would have been...

> I have data in EPSG:3857 but Leaflet will only accept EPSG:4326 `LatLng`s, how can I add my data?

Then the answer would have been:

You will have to project your data from EPSG:3857. Use `proj4js`, or `proj4leaflet`, or simply:

```
var coords4326 = L.Projection.SphericalMercator.unproject(coords3857);
```

Comment: I have a doubt here. I believe Leaflet uses EPSG:3857. But my coordinates were EPSG:4326. Now I need to convert EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857. How can I achieve this? Your answer was for the other way. Correct me If I am wrong in my question.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310091/what-does-the-default-crs-being-epsg3857-in-leaflet-mean