# Project Mercator coordinates at a specified zoom level in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, mapbox-gl-js

I am struggling a bit moving from Leaflet to Mapbox. I have geojson with coordinates like `[68100095, 100779149]`, which I am told are Mercator x/y coordinates at a zoom level of 20. This is how the data is stored.

In Leaflet, I could translate these coordinates to latitude and longitude using `map.unproject([68100095, 100779149], 20`, specifying the coordinates and then the zoom level. It works as intended.

In Mapbox, `unproject` does not allow you to specify a zoom level, and unprojects based on your current zoom level, which I cannot guarantee. My attempted solution is to use Proj4js and an NPM package called `mercator-projection`, which is meant to project mercator coordinates to latitude/longitude. My solution, which yields erratic results, is as follows:

```
function mercator_to_lnglat(x, y) {
    const SCALE_ADJUSTMENT = 564.248588    //Adjust for zoom level of 20

    let scaledPoint = [x/SCALE_ADJUSTMENT, y/SCALE_ADJUSTMENT]
    let projectedPoint = proj4("GOOGLE", "WGS84", scaledPoint)
    let latlng = merc.fromPointToLatLng({x: projectedPoint[0], y: projectedPoint[1]})

    return latlng
}
```

`SCALE_ADJUSTMENT` here is a magic number I got from [this ArcGIS link](https://git.2020.dev/2020/precision-util/-/blob/goldmine-qt6/include/precision/util/point/MercatorPoint.h#L36) that calculated an equivalent scaling factor for a zoom level of 20.

I'm no GIS expert, so I would be thrilled if anyone could point out what I'm doing incorrectly here.

Comment: This is helpful, and explains some of what I was seeing in the Leaflet source! I'll follow that lead when I get back to it.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help. It was much simpler than I was making it, but I never would have got it without your explainer.

If you would like to formulate your guidance as an answer, I would gladly accept and add my specific solution as a comment. (There is a package called coordinates2pixels that did the thinking, once you set me on the right path.) If I don't hear back after a day or so, I'll go ahead and answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `map.project` and `map.unproject` methods in Leaflet for projecting/unprojecting coordinates, these are not Mercator coordinates, but *"pixel coordinates relative to the CRS origin"*, see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-conversion-methods.

If you want to project/unproject Mercator coordinates in Leaflet, you have to use `.project` and `.unproject` methods of `L.CRS.EPSG3857` projection, see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#crs.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310091/what-does-the-default-crs-being-epsg3857-in-leaflet-mean as well.

Comment: Thank you again. Specific to my question about Mapbox but not specific to Mapbox or Leaflet, my solution involved using the npm package coordinates2pixels (https://www.npmjs.com/package/coordinates2pixels) and not bothering with map project/unproject.